# How to fix mongoose typescript error on AWS lambda?

Tags: typescript, mongoose, serverless-framework

I am trying to set up a simple call to a Mongo Atlas Database using the serverless framework, AWS lambda and mongoose.

I am currently set up using the latest command from serverless for typescript: `create -t aws-nodejs-typescript`

`serverless.yaml`

```
plugins:
  - serverless-webpack

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  region: us-east-1
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "lib",
    "removeComments": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

I have a file that is imported to handle the actual connection.

`connect.ts`

```
export const mongoose = require('mongoose')
export const Schema = mongoose.Schema

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise
let isConnected: boolean = false

export const connectToDatabase = () => {
  if (isConnected) {
    console.log('using existing database connection')
    return Promise.resolve()
  } else {
    console.log('using new database connection', { isConnected })
    return mongoose
      .connect(
        encodeURI(`${process.env.DB}`)
      )
      .then((db: any) => {
        console.log(db)
        isConnected = true
      })
  }
}
```

which is then imported to my handler functions.

`handler.ts`

```
import {
  connectToDatabase,
  defaultResponseHeader,
} from '../utils/mongo-helpers'
import { user } from '../utils/users'

module.exports.hello = async (event, context) => {
  console.log('started')
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false

  console.log(user)
  connectToDatabase().then(() => {
    console.log('in connect')
    const doc = user.findOne()
    console.log(doc)
    console.log(event)

    return doc
  })
}
```

When I deploy this to AWS lambda and try to test I get the following error:

```
  "errorMessage": "Unexpected token *",
  "errorType": "SyntaxError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "SyntaxError: Unexpected token *",
    "createScript (vm.js:80:10)",
    "Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)",
    "Module._compile (module.js:616:28)",
    "Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)",
    "Module.load (module.js:565:32)",
    "tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)",
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)",
    "Module.require (module.js:596:17)",
    "require (internal/module.js:11:18)"
  ]
}
```

along with the following Log

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
```

It looks like this is an error from compilation or from something not being imported correctly.

I've tried different versions of importing or requiring mongoose but nothing seems to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

At least exporting the require('mongoose') seems like something that's not needed.

What worked for me was just following the official guidelines:
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/lambda.html

and using serverless-plugin-typescript:
https://github.com/prisma/serverless-plugin-typescript